# Convert .bin to .png for files located in word/embedding of a word.zip file

Tags: vba, ms-word, zip, png

I am stuck at this problem for some hours now.

I have a wordfile with embedded OLE objects. The OLE-Objects are PNG-files.

I unzipped the word-file via renaming it to .zip and found the files I need via **\document.xml** and **_rels\document.xml.rels** whereby I could identify the needed OLE-Object in the **documents.xml** and the **r:id** under **<v:imagedata>** linked to the respective OLE-Object in the **document.xml.rels**.

Now when I open the OLE-Object via the word file, it is recognized as expected as a PNG. When I look it up under **\embeddings\oleObject1.bin**, it is no longer a png, but a bin instead.

Now simply renaming the bin to png does not work...

My question would be: How do I turn this bin into a graphics format I can use?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -3):

*.bin streams are themselves zip archives. When you extract them you will find their true contents along with some meta-data.

Comment: At least in my case (embedded .json file), this is certainly not the case. If I open the `.bin` file I can see the json content inside, surrounded by a bunch of binary data. The bin file also does not start with the zip magic bytes.